# Postgres- have to_timestamp() ignore/not read a specific character in middle of date/time string

Tags: postgresql

I have raw text column with values like '2012-07-26T10:33:34' and '2012-07-26T10:56:16'.  In Java using Joda-Time I can easily convert this to/from a date by calling

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")`.

In Postgres how would I ignore this 'T' character in the middle?

I have tried `'YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ss'` but get the error

*> ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the T is allowed in an ANSI ANSI timestamp literal, so the following should work.

```
select timestamp '2012-07-26T10:33:34';
```

You say you have a text column, so you probably need something like this:

```
create table foo (ts text);
insert into foo values ('2012-07-26T10:33:34')
select cast(ts as timestamp)
from foo;
```

This works as well:

```
select to_timestamp(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
from foo;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0b369/1

Comment: had a similar issue but even thought the `CAST` solution above seems to work

`SELECT CAST('2012-07-26T10:33:34' AS TIMESTAMP);`

the `TO_TIMESTAMP` **DOES NOT**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the `CAST` solution does work

```sql
SELECT CAST('2012-07-26T10:33:34' AS TIMESTAMP);

      timestamp
---------------------
 2012-07-26 10:33:34
```

but the `TO_TIMESTAMP` with just a space *or* a `T`

**DOES NOT WORK**

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2012-07-26T10:33:34', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

ERROR:  invalid value "T1" for "HH24"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.
```

**NOR DOES THIS** using a `T`

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2012-07-26T10:33:34', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS');

      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2012-07-26 00:03:34+10
```

but surprisingly using lower case `hh24` and an uppercase `T`

**DOES WORK**

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2012-07-26T10:33:34', 'YYYY-MM-DDThh24:MI:SS');

      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2012-07-26 10:33:34+10
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make a space between T and following HH24 and it also works:
select TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-11-09T06:14:00+03', 'YYYY-MM-DDT HH24:MI:SS');

| to_timestamp |
| --- |
| 2022-11-09 06:14:00.000 +0300 |